# When Do I Have An Invertible Matrix of Partial Derivatives?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, jacobian

I have some function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Moreover $f(a,b,c, \dots, n)=1$. I am using the implicit function theorem to define a function for one argument $a$ in terms of another, $b$. I know that in order to use the IFT, it needs to be the case that the Jacobian of partial derivatives is invertible. What does this looks like? When is this the case? When all derivatives are non-zero?

Do I only consider the matrix of all partial derivatives, even when I want only to define $a$ as a function of $b$?

Comment: I [edit]ed this question since ([tag:functional-analysis]) is the study of *infinite* dimensional vector spaces.  This question only involves finite dimensional ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, it's only when $m = n$ that the inverse of the Jacobian makes sense (i.e., when the matrix is square).

Comment: @AlkaKadri, so you can't apply the IFT with a functions of many variables?

Comment: @user526463 Do you mean the IFT (Implicit function theorem)? You certainly can, you just need to be careful about what you mean by Jacobian. You only need a certain part of the Jacobian to be invertible, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Definitions

Comment: @AlkaKadri Yes, Implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on our discussion, if you have $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $a = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{n - 1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n - 1}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, then you need to consider
\begin{align}
  J(f(a,b)) &= \left[\begin{array}{c c c | c} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}    \end{array}\right]
\end{align}
By the [IFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Definitions), you need $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$ to be "invertible". For a $1 \times 1$ matrix (i.e, just a scalar), this just means that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \ne 0$. What exactly does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$ represent? $x_n$ is going to be the variable that you're writing as a function of the remaining variables, and the IFT says you can do this so long as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \ne 0$.

Comment: Only if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \ne 0$? Is it still permisible if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 0$?

Comment: Yeah. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 0$, however, means that you cannot write the variable $x_1$ as a function of the rest of the variables. This doesn't affect your ability to write another variable as a function of the others.

Comment: The classic example is the unit circle. I would highly recommend you check out the Wikipedia page I linked.

Answer (score 0):

A linear map (given by a matrix, $M$) is invertible when $\det M \neq 0$.

Comment: What does the matrix look like (see my update)

Comment: @user526463 Look up how to calculate a determinant.